# Como poner un gif en una sección concreta de una web que es un fullscreen image background

Tags: html5, css3, animación, gif

Un cliente con una web que tiene una home que es una imagen en fullscreen, me pide que le ponga un gif. Tiene un cocodrilo que representa un virus y los ojos de este animal se abren y se cierran. Pongo una captura de ejemplo para mostrar lo que quisiera hacer. Y este gif tiene que estar fijo de manera que si se visita esta web con una pantalla móvil este no se mueva, no importa si queda oculto.
[image: ejemplo del trabajo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `position: fixed` ([documentación](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)) en el css del `div` que contenga el gif:

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: Xpx; right: Ypx;" >
    <img src="loading.gif" alt="COCODRILOOOOOOOOO" />
</div>
```

Dónde X e Y es la posición (X,Y) en la pantalla.

Comment: Excel·lent aportació!! gracias!

Comment: de res! piensa que puedes utilizar `bottom`,`top`,`right` y `left` indistintamente para aplicar lo que necesites. En tu caso creo que lo mejor es `bottom` y `right`